# Trying to remove class remove html element after successful ajax post

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to remove a class from an element after a successful post. The code below is simplified for ease and is not removing the class.

I'm not sure what the issue is.

Page element:

```
    <div class="hide-lorem form-group row" id="LoremId">
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            Lorem
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    data: $("#LoremHandler").serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        var tr = "";

                        $("#LoremId").removeClass("hide-lorem");

                        //Append each row to html table
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.Jumps.length; i++) {
                            var date = dateFormatter(data.Jumps[i].LoremDate);
                            tr = $("<tr/>");
                            tr.append("<td>" + date + "</td>");
                            tr.append("<td>&pound;" + data.Jumps[i].LoremPlace + "</td>");
                            $("table").append(tr);

                        }
                    },
                    failure: function(response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    error: function(response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Do `console.log(document.getElementById("LoremId").classList;` after the AJAX call and show what it says.

Comment: See the working solution below. Let me know hope this helps.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping The OP has an ID on the element, so that code should work.

Comment: Your code looks right. Could it be possible there's another element with the same id defined above this snippet?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thanks for your input and downvoting my answer. Considering that the OP still is happy with the solution. I have consider that he might have similar `ID` on that page hence why i suggested a straight and working solution with a `class`. Anyways! I wish you best of luck.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping It's nothing personal. Good answers answer the question. You've provided a work around, but the question has not been answered, hence the down vote. Remember, Stack Overflow is a knowledge base for future questions that people may have. Ask yourself, if someone else with a similar problem finds this page and this answer, will it actually solve their problem?

Comment: @ScottMarcus All good. I did not take personal or never will. As The OP needed a fix and i am sure using `ID's` are not ideal and isn't suggested anywhere especially if you are working around jQuery. I would assume that you are not suggesting people to use 'ID,s' to get things done. As i said Best of luck and thanks for your valuable input on Stack overflow.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Again, remember the purpose of Stack Overflow. It's  not to simply provide working code. It's to provide answers to the questions that explain the problem and the solution so that others can be helped in the future. After doing that, if you have suggestions on how to make the code better, feel free to add that, but you should always strive to answer the question first and foremost. While using an `id` isn't always the best approach, it is the approach that the OP has taken here and there may be reasons beyond what's been stated for doing so. Your "answer" side steps that.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Best of luck. Have a good day.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping *ID's are not ideal and isn't suggested anywhere especially if you are working around jQuery* <-- (FYI) the use of JQuery does not have any bearing on the pro or con use of an `id`, nor is there any guidance anywhere stating that `id`s are to be avoided, "especially if you are using JQuery".

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thanks for your input. I appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things to highlight.

**Issue:** You are trying to removeClass from an `ID` as you might have other ID's on the page with same name.

**Reason:** Using an `ID` is not ideal as you i am assuming that you might have other ID with same name. Which is causing this issue.

**Simple and suggested workaround:** I would suggest to add `class` to your element and then `removeClass()` from that element. I have added a LoremId as class in your `div` as well.

Please see the working code below:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: $("#LoremHandler").serialize(),
  success: function(data) {
    var tr = "";

    $(".LoremId").removeClass("hide-lorem");

    //Append each row to html table
    for (var i = 0; i < data.Jumps.length; i++) {
      var date = dateFormatter(data.Jumps[i].LoremDate);
      tr = $("<tr/>");
      tr.append("<td>" + date + "</td>");
      tr.append("<td>&pound;" + data.Jumps[i].LoremPlace + "</td>");
      $("table").append(tr);

    }
  },
  failure: function(response) {
    alert(response.responseText);
  },
  error: function(response) {
    alert(response.responseText);
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="hide-lorem form-group row LoremId" id="LoremId">
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    Lorem
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: There is an ID on the element that the OP is trying to remove the class on, so `$("#LoremId").removeClass()` is fine.

Comment: @nless Cheers. Glad i could help.

Comment: @nless You're welcome. Don't forget to up vote and mark as "the" answer.